# javascript instanceof get type from string name

Tags: javascript, instanceof

Let's say I have this (assume the name variable is "receiver"):

```
if (!(receiver instanceof com.HTMLReceiver)) {
    throw new com.IllegalArgumentException(
        name + " is not an instance of com.HTMLReceiver.");
}
```

I'd like to factor this code out into a common method so I could call it like this:

```
Helper.checkInstance(receiver, "com.HTMLReceiver");
```

But I don't know of a way to convert the  `com.HTMLReceiver` from a string to its actual type so I can use `instanceof` on it.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it as:

```
Helper.checkInstance(receiver, com.HTMLReceiver);
```

This will not allow you print a type name ("com.HTMLReceiver").

or:

```
Helper.checkInstance(receiver, com.HTMLReceiver, "com.HTMLReceiver");
```

You use the user string in the print.

Note that the same type can have multiple type names

```
var foo = com.HTMLReceiver;
```

`foo` and `com.HTMLReceiver` are names for the same thing.

JavaScript has no way of going from type to type name itself.

If you only pass in the String, I think the only general solution is eval.

Comment: Seems that he wants to get the *name* of the constructor, and concatenate it to the string argument of the exception...

Comment: Cool, that looks promising. But why doesn't it work with "instanceof Number"?

Comment: Not sure what `name` refers to, but it looks like it has something to do with `receiver`.

Comment: It will work with Number.  However, number literals are not instances of Number. :)  `3 instanceof Number` is false, but `new Number(3) instanceof Number` is true.

Comment: @Anurag - Refer to first paragraph: "assume the name variable is "receiver""

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - LOL, is there any way to make it work for the 3 instanceof Number case, or is there some other way that can be handled?

Comment: `typeof receiver == 'number'`

Comment: @Anurag - Yes, it seems primitives and class types have to be handled with separate cases. Thanks for your help. Thank you as well Matthew!